# Bringing tab to front in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

When I use `setSelectedComponent` or `setSelectedIndex` on a `JTabbedPane` object, the panel always comes up in my UI.  However, sometimes the tab associated with the panel remains hidden.  In other words, the tab does not scroll to a visible portion of the tabbed pane.

How can I fix this?  I have tried the cheesy select one index, then select desired index, as well as several other more elegant things, but arrrrgh!!

Help me if you can.

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your call is not done on EDT. Wrap it with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: BTW, do I need to wrap similar code that is within a ListCellRenderer?  Or is that too vague a question do to where the List may be?

Comment: Any code which has to do with UI (even models) has to run on EDT. You can check if you are on it by using SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()

Comment: Renderers are used in painting components, so their code runs on EDT already. But you can check to be sure

Comment: Eugene, the previously referenced code, now using invokeLater has started to exhibit the same problem as before.  Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, I have wrapped it directly in the Runnable for the invokeLater, as well as used Devon's pattern below - no difference.  So, it must be on the EDT.

Comment: So what is inside your Runnable now?

Comment: And is it running at all? Devon's code is not doing anything if it is on EDT

Comment: I am having the same problem as Todd. Wrapping the setSelectedComponent code inside a runnable doesn't scroll the tab even though the actual panel appears on screen.

Comment: the only workaround i was able to come up with was manually selecting tab 0 then selecting the new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patter you can use if you have a method that alters swing components, or their models and so must be called on the EDT, but may be called from a background thread. This ensures *func* **always** runs on the EDT:

```
void func(final Type1 arg1, final Type2 arg2) {

    if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                func(arg1, arg2);
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    // method code goes here
}
```