# Auto Click to particular tab when button is clicked in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I have a `JTabbedPane` with 5 tabs in it. I also got 3 other buttons in same `JFrame` where my JTabbedPane is added. I want to make the user able move to particular tab when a particular button is clicked. Here is the image example

[image]

Now for example if user clicks `Button 1` then `tab One` should be opened and similarly when `button 2` is clicked  then `tab Two` should be opened and so for third one.

Here is my code to add these JTabbedPane and buttons.

```
public class TabsAndButtons
{
    public TabsAndButtons()
    {
       JTabbedPane tabsPane = new JTabbedPane();
       tabsPane.add("One", new JPanel());
       tabsPane.add("Two", new JPanel());
       tabsPane.add("Three", new JPanel());
       tabsPane.add("Four", new JPanel());
       tabsPane.add("Five", new JPanel());

       JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
       Panel.add(tabsPane);

       JButton Button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
       Panel.add(Button1);
       JButton Button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
       Panel.add(Button2);
       JButton Button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
       Panel.add(Button3);

       JFrame MainFrame = new JFrame("JTabbedPane and Buttons");
       MainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       MainFrame.getContentPane().add(Panel );
       MainFrame.pack();
       MainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
           new TabsAndButtons();
       });
    }
}
```

The actual purpose of such action is very lengthy and has a lot details which will make the question dull so I am asking the main task where I stucked. Thanks for your kind support and time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bringing tab to front in JTabbedPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235644/bringing-tab-to-front-in-jtabbedpane)

Comment: No that's totally different thing

Comment: Yeah... you were meant to use the question I referenced as the core of an action listener handler, but I suppose I should have spelled it out. I think you probably realize that it's not "totally different."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `button.addActionListener() to execute code when a button is clicked. The code that you want to execute is probably`tabsPane. setSelectedIndex(i)`where`i` is the index of the tab that you want to show.

You might also want to move the `JTabbedPane tabsPane` into a member variable, or mark it with `final`, to make sure that it can be accessed from within the action listener.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I just needed an idea so you gave me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ActionListener` to each of the buttons. Then in the ActionListener you can invoke the `setSelected(...)` method of the tabbed pane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more information and examples.

Also, variable name should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the EventListener for the Buttons the Method `setSelectedIndex(int index)` on your JTabbedPane.
The Referenz: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29